# VB6 declare webbrowser in module

Tags: mysql, vb6, webbrowser-control

I'm new in VB6 and I got a project that makes an internet connection using webbrowser. The function that makes it is in a module described below and the project calls it in main Forms.

Forms:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Me.Top = 585
    Me.Left = 12090

    Call BuscaPais.Paises(48, -1)
End Sub
```

Module BuscaPais:

```
Sub Paises(clifor, tempodia)

    Dim db As New ADODB.Connection
    db.Open "Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};Uid=root;Pwd=03072003;Server=xxx.xxx.xx.xx;Port=xxx;Option=xxx;STMT=;Database=xxx"

    SQL = "select cd_ocorrencia, vl_latitude, vl_longitude from ocorrencias where dt_hora >= date_format(date_add(current_timestamp, interval " & tempodia & " day), '%Y/%m/%d') "
    SQL = SQL & " and cd_status <> 99 and ds_pais = '' and vl_latitude <> '0.000000' and vl_longitude <> '0.000000' order by cd_ocorrencia asc "
    Set RS = db.Execute(SQL)
    While Not RS.EOF

        WB.Navigate2 "http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=xml&lat=" & Replace(RS!vl_latitude, ",", ".") & "&lon=" & Replace(RS!vl_longitude, ",", ".") & "&zoom=18&addressdetails=1"
        t = Timer
        Do Until WB.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
            checktime = Timer - t
            If checktime >= 30 Then
                WB.Stop
                DoEvents
            End If
            DoEvents
        Loop


        If InStr(WB.Document.body.innertext, "A página XML não pode ser exibida") = 0 Then
            Pais = UCase(Mid(WB.Document.body.innertext, InStr(WB.Document.body.innertext, "</country_code>") - 2, 2))
            db.Execute ("update ocorrencias set ds_pais = '" & Pais & "' where cd_ocorrencia = " & RS!cd_ocorrencia)
        End If

        Pais = ""

    RS.MoveNext
    Wend
    RS.Close

End Sub
```

It returns an error `Object Required` in `WB.Navigate2` line. If I put this function inside Forms it works fine. How can I declare a webbrowser inside a module? I tried using `Dim WB as New WebBrowser_V1` but I get another error: `Object doesn't support this property or method`

Comment: Just pass WB as a *parameter* to the function. No need to couple themodule to your particular form.

Comment: @wqw Could you post an answer for me to accept your answer as resolved?!

Comment: Will do it if it's for you good karma only -- I don't need the points. . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it just referencing the main form:

```
Sub Paises(clifor, tempodia)

    Dim db As New ADODB.Connection
    db.Open "Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};Uid=root;Pwd=03072003;Server=xxx.xxx.xx.xx;Port=xxx;Option=xxx;STMT=;Database=xxx"

    SQL = "select cd_ocorrencia, vl_latitude, vl_longitude from ocorrencias where dt_hora >= date_format(date_add(current_timestamp, interval " & tempodia & " day), '%Y/%m/%d') "
    SQL = SQL & " and cd_status <> 99 and ds_pais = '' and vl_latitude <> '0.000000' and vl_longitude <> '0.000000' order by cd_ocorrencia asc "
    Set RS = db.Execute(SQL)
    While Not RS.EOF

        mainform.WB.Navigate2 "http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=xml&lat=" & Replace(RS!vl_latitude, ",", ".") & "&lon=" & Replace(RS!vl_longitude, ",", ".") & "&zoom=18&addressdetails=1"
        t = Timer
        Do Until mainform.WB.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
            checktime = Timer - t
            If checktime >= 30 Then
                mainform.WB.Stop
                DoEvents
            End If
            DoEvents
        Loop


        If InStr(mainform.WB.Document.body.innertext, "A página XML não pode ser exibida") = 0 Then
            Pais = UCase(Mid(mainform.WB.Document.body.innertext, InStr(mainform.WB.Document.body.innertext, "</country_code>") - 2, 2))
            db.Execute ("update ocorrencias set ds_pais = '" & Pais & "' where cd_ocorrencia = " & RS!cd_ocorrencia)
        End If

        Pais = ""

    RS.MoveNext
    Wend
    RS.Close

End Sub
```